# How can I use all classes from namespace instead of listing them all individually?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, namespaces, entity

In my Controller I list all entities I have:

```
use App\Entity\Members;
use App\Entity\Products;
use App\Entity\Projects;
```

But because new Entities will automatically be created, I need instead something like

```
use AllEntities;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no available option in PHP to import all classes from particular namespace at once.

In order to use a particular class you need to define so called Fully-qualified class name so it means to use `use` keyword for each class OR the other option is to import the namespace but when instantiating or using that class as a static for example you need to use imported namespace followed by `\` and the class name.

For example:
    
    `use Foo\Bar;
    $classOne = new Bar\ClassOne();
    $classTwo = new Bar\ClassTwo();`

This is valid when there is only one namespace ending with `Bar` imported.
Otherwise you need to alias each one - the same applies to repeated class names - they also need to be aliased. This is about the built-in possibilities.

When it comes to your particular case - if you automatically create new entities which means that you generate new code - the only solution I see here is to expand your generation capabilities for generating some new code in places you need it.